# Express.js : req.body weirdly gets stacked

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

**EDIT :**

To sum up the problem : when I post something using ajax the first time, it sets the req.body value, but this value is never reset, even if I load a page (F5) again, or if I perform another POST request : the data remains set, and it remains at the same value and is never updated again (until I reset the server)

**ORIGINAL POST :**

I'm noob at using Express.js.

I'm performing a very basic AJAX form submission using the code below.

```
sites_edit: function(req, res)
{
    if (req.route.method == 'post')
    {
        //console.log('========== POST');
        var oSite = req.param('site');
        var SiteModel = models.Site;
        //console.log(oSite);
        //console.log(req.body);

        var pCallback = function()
        {
            oSite.owner = app.getOwner();
            new SiteModel(oSite).save(function(e)
            {
                //console.log('saved.');
                //console.log(e);
                var aRet = app.analyzeSave(e);
                if (aRet.success)
                    aRet.site = oSite;

                res.json(aRet);
            });
        };

        if (oSite.id)
        {
            models.Site.findById(oSite.id, function(err, oTmpSite)
            {
                if (err)
                    throw new Error(err);

                if (oTmpSite.owner != app.getOwner().id)
                    throw new Exception('bad owner');

                pCallback();
            });
        }
        else
            pCallback();

        return;
    }

    // Handling GET request here
    // (...)
}
```

Submitted data is like :

```
site[id]:
site[name]:
site[address]:
site[postal_code]:
site[city]:
site[phone]:
site[email]:
```

The problem is, when I post the form the first time, I get (generated) errors for the missing fields. But if I submit it another time, I get only one event in network monitoring of Firebug, but I get TWO new node.js POST calls, including "headers already sent" errors. And in addition, the data in req.body gets stacked.

I mean, I get the following output in console :

```
Starting server in environment: local
Express app started on port 80
POST /configuration/site/enregistrer 200 9ms - 262
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22)
    at next (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:153:13)
    at multipart (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:60:27)
    at module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:57:9)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencode
d.js:68:11)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:90:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1704:22)
POST /configuration/site/enregistrer 200 10ms - 128
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22)
    at next (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:153:13)
    at multipart (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:60:27)
    at module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:57:9)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencode
d.js:68:11)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:90:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1704:22)
POST /configuration/site/enregistrer 200 7ms - 128
```

If I debug the req.body value, I get :

```
// First AJAX submit
{ site:
   { id: '',
     name: '',
     address: '',
     postal_code: '',
     city: '',
     phone: '',
     email: '' } }
// Second AJAX submit
{ site:
   { id: '',
     name: [ '', '' ],
     address: [ '', '' ],
     postal_code: [ '', '' ],
     city: [ '', '' ],
     phone: [ '', '' ],
     email: [ 'site[id]=', '' ] } }
// And another POST request is (strangely) handled by Express.js during the 2nd AJAX submit, which leads to third dump of the (apparently updated) variable
{ site:
   { id: '',
     name: [ '', '', '' ],
     address: [ '', '', '' ],
     postal_code: [ '', '', '' ],
     city: [ '', '', '' ],
     phone: [ '', '', '' ],
     email: [ 'site[id]=', 'site[id]=', '' ] } }
```

Seriously, what the hell is happening here? Is that even remotely possible?

Thank you a lot in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**

If I refresh the page after having submitted the form one time, I get DOZENS of "headers already sent" errors, spread among the different HTTP requests (for getting static js/css files).

Errors like below:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22)
    at next (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:153:13)
    at multipart (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:60:27)
    at module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:57:9)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencode
d.js:68:11)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
    at Object.resume (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\pause\index.js:25:18)
    at resume (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:61:13)
    at SendStream.error (E:\nodejs\projects\arent\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:73:37)
```

If I refresh the page BEFORE submitting in AJAX, I do never get these errors.

Comment: PS: also, if you see any bad node.js newbie code above, PLEASE let me know, because I'm really new at this and I'd like to get better and always use best practices. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the solution is not obvious.

But your expressjs code is weird: my method treatment is often similar to:

```
app.post('/enregistrer/:site', function (req, res) {
  ...
}
```

so that I don't have to test the `req.route.method`.

The error message `Can't set headers after they are sent.` suggests that you don't end the response, and that the next responses are in the same.

However, you use `res.json`, which should behave like `res.send`. So, the response should be sent.

Or, you use `res.send` ou `res.json` twice in the response code, then sending again the headers the second time?

Comment: I went down to only displaying req.body, and using res.send('ok'), but the same error happened. Here is a paste of the server side output (I'm only doing two ajax POST, but the second time I POST using ajax, the server handles two http requests, and the req.body is all messed up) : http://pastebin.com/QNA085p8

Comment: Some news : I updated Node.js (was at version 0.8.1), and now I don't have the same error. Exit the "headers already sent" errors. Now the error is that the POST data (req.body) remains the same from one ajax call to another, whereas I (of course) change it client-side. Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code's structure still puzzles me. Perhaps it's the cause of your server's responding only to the first request of each method? Didn't you try http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable

Comment: What is it about my code's structure? I'm new to node.js so there are plenty of things for me to learn. I have a big app, that uses 3 sub-apps (frontend, admin, and a portal). Each sub-app includes a router file, that is basically associating an URL to a function inside a controller class. The code I showed is the aforementioned function. And I reduced the function code to its minimum : displaying req.body, and returning a response text. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: I created a tiny app to reproduce the bug, unfortunately it works fine. So there is a problem with my app, or at least with a module I am using...